# Efecto agrandar imagen no funciona - CSS HTML

Tags: html, css

Dispongo de un código HTML al que está asociado un .css
¿Por qué no surte efecto mi animación en la imagen?

```css
    .logo:hover{
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
     -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
     transform: scale(1.3);
    }
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <center>
    <!-- Añadimos en el CSS un efecto de enfoque en la imagen -->
    <img src="http://imagenpng.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/imagenes-png-635x508.png" height="160" width="380"/>
  </center>
</div>
```

Comment: Si que funciona, agrandarse cuando pasas por encima lo hace. Pero, ¿lo quieres animado?

Comment: Efectivamente funciona, el resto de propiedades css funcionan? Seguramente sea la llamada al archivo css lo que falle.

Comment: para ver como se anima, debes hacer un `transition` https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Falta una transición (`transition`: [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)) en tu CSS para que haga la animación de agrandarse.

```css
    .logo:hover{
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
     -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
     transform: scale(1.3);
        transition: transform .5s;
    }
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <center>
    <!-- Añadimos en el CSS un efecto de enfoque en la imagen -->
    <img src="http://imagenpng.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/imagenes-png-635x508.png" height="160" width="380"/>
  </center>
</div>
```